# Which is better Thrift vs RESTful services?

Tags: java, php, web-services, rest, thrift

I am in a juncture to decide between Thrift and using plain RESTful services between client and server. Moreover I am stuck with whether to use socket for communication or just go with webservice as is considering its long and proven track record. Thrift on the other hand is unknown with less documentation and moreover port is needed to be opened. Kind of app I am having is a website wih php(client) and java (service layer) and for this integration I am trying to assess Thrift/REST.

1. What would be challenge in using socket/ports vs 8080?
2. Will there be any performance benefit in any of the approaches?
3. Is  there be any other option also?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Web service is a bit more robust and will likely be more extensible as the application grows. If you're not confident in handling the socket routines and all of the nuances associated with that (socket connects, disconnects, errors, etc), then simply adding a service to an existing web service in something like php, or using rails with ruby, or tomcat with Java.

As far as the performance concerns, it can depend on that use case of the thrift/restful interface and the underlying systems.. In a lot of cases, the actions your api perform is more 'expensive' than handling the api request.

And as for which, i'm a fan of REST but thats personal preference.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks Jizaymes.
In addition to what I had asked, I want to ask one more question-should socket be considered as a choice in sending data over internet?

Comment: If you mean like a UNIX socket then no. Only TCP/UDP would be viable